# Point wise Steps Should be Documented for Using Teams Cloud Communication Call API

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are trying to develop CTI Connector for CRM and Microsoft Teams. We understand rights required to implement calling API but failed to initiate sample call from Postman. We registered application and given required permission (Application Permission) but always getting "Application Not Registered".
One thing which is not clear from Microsoft Documentation for Cloud Communication API is do we need to register our application as Bot.
It will be better if point-wise steps required to implement calling API documented on Microsoft Site.

If anyone have successfully tried Calling API for Teams then it will be great if you can suggestv the steps.

Thanks & Regards,
Umesh

Comment: Are you trying to use Bots to make calls in Teams?

Comment: I am writing server based application which will take MakeCall request from agents who has Microsoft Teams Client as Telephone. Do I need to register my application as BOT ?

Comment: Yes, Please follow [Calling and meeting bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) docs.